# wp-admin redirects to 404 not found nginx 1.10.0

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Can you please help me to edit my Nginx script.I have problem with access to https://myurl.wp-admin.php redirects to 404 not found nginx  1.10.0.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        listen 443 ssl;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html;

        server_name _;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/csr/ssl_altr/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/csr/ssl_altr/nginx.key;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
                root /var/www/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `https://example.com/wp-admin/`? That URL should find `wp-admin/index.php`

Comment: Yes i mean “ https://example.com/wp-admin “ _ also wp-admin/index.php same error 404 error

Comment: Where are the wordpress files installed on your server - the exact path to `wp-admin/index.php`?

Comment: First off backup your nginx file then start removing `location` blocks one by one And then restart nginx.

Comment: Yes in the exact file " we-admin/index.php "

Comment: The full path? For example: `/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-admin/index.php`?

Comment: This is my full path WordPress                                                                     " /var/www/html/wp-admin/index.php "

Comment: Hii MrJack Mcfreder ;                                                                                               I was removing                                                                                                                         "" location = /50x.html {
     root /var/www/html;
        } ""                                                                                                           nothing happening the error still. then I was removing the other locations same Error happening.

Comment: When access url (https://example.com/wp-admin)                                                its redirect to  (https://example.com/wp-admin/wordpress/wp-login.php)      and the page showing this Error 404

Comment: Change "listen 443 ssl;" for "listen [::]:443 ssl;"